# link translation in apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

Is it possible in apache rever to have link translation?

We want to migrate our ISA 2006 webservices to Apache with reverse proxy but the link translation ISA uses isnt an option in mod_proxy it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the full capabilities of the link-translation you're using, but it sounds like you want to enable [mod_proxy_html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) and set up some `ProxyHTMLURLMap` directives.